# Spoofing & Rotating MAC address using Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a simple Applescript that rotates the MAC address from a selection of defined numbers every 10 minutes - I've put the following together as a workflow in Automator and it's running without throwing any errors up, but it doesn't seem to be working!

I'm not sure why it's not, but it's the first Apple Script I've written so I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple

```
on run
tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:46" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:40" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:41" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:42" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:43" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:44" password "password" with administrator privileges


delay 600

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:45" password "password" with administrator privileges

delay 100

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "sudo ifconfig en2 ether 00:26:08:ff:85:ae" password "password" with administrator privileges


end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- airport -z
- Quit system preferences.
- Run scselect -n on terminal.

> -n  Delay changing the system's "location" until the next system boot (or the next time that the system configuration preferences are
>   changed).

- run sudo ifconfig en2 ether 4E:53:50:4F:4F:46

Comment: Thanks Parag - Afraid I'm a little lost with your answer, is there any way you could clarify further?

Comment: Take a look at http://maymay.net/blog/2011/03/29/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-on-mac-os-x-for-reals/ and http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/